# How can I get rid of the yellow tint in the image from my Macbook's camera

Tags: macbook, camera

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Macbook Pro.  After building facetimehd driver from source and struggling with the installation of the driver for a bit, the camera is now finally working - however the image that goes across to people in video calls has a definite yellow tint to it.

After some searching I discovered `guvcview` and tried to use it to tune hue and saturation values.  While this has definitely led to an improvement, the yellow tint is still quite evident.  At least now I can choose between "hot pink" and "mordor red" if I wanted to.  Instead what I would very much like is just a fairly plain neutral colouring.

Comment: Do you have the option to change white balance?

Comment: The only option I seem to have that relates to white balance, is an on/off checkbox that is labeled "White balance, Automatic:".  Changing its state does not appear to have any effect on the image.

Comment: Maybe in config file of this software there is some setting about. If you turn off AWB you should set manually (somehow) the temperature and tint as it is in photography

Answer (score 0):

Copying the calibration files from the Bootcamp install worked for me. Quoting from https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Extracting-the-sensor-calibration-files :

> Note: I've only tested this on 1871_01XX.dat. Use at your own risk and
> report any errors.
>
> When using the set files (sensor calibration settings) the colors look
> much better. I only know how to extract them from the windows bootcamp
> driver. These are the steps you can follow:
>
> 1. Download driver package from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837
> 2. Extract the \BootCamp\Drivers\Apple\AppleCamera64.exe file
> 3. Run: unrar x AppleCamera64.exe You should now have the AppleCamera.sys file which is the driver containing the set files.
> 4. Run the following commands:
>
>    ```
>    dd bs=1 skip=1663920 count=33060 if=AppleCamera.sys of=9112_01XX.dat
>    dd bs=1 skip=1644880 count=19040 if=AppleCamera.sys of=1771_01XX.dat
>    dd bs=1 skip=1606800 count=19040 if=AppleCamera.sys of=1871_01XX.dat
>    dd bs=1 skip=1625840 count=19040 if=AppleCamera.sys of=1874_01XX.dat
>    ```
>
> You should now have the four .dat files with the follow md5sum
> checksums:
>
> ```
> a1831db76ebd83e45a016f8c94039406  1771_01XX.dat
> 017996a51c95c6e11bc62683ad1f356b  1871_01XX.dat
> 3c3cdc590e628fe3d472472ca4d74357  1874_01XX.dat
> 479ae9b2b7ab018d63843d777a3886d1  9112_01XX.dat
> ```
>
> Copy the .dat files into your facetimehd firmware directory (eg.
> /lib/firmware/facetimehd/)
>
> 5. Reload the driver
> 6. Check that you don't get the "Direct firmware load for facetimehd..." error.
>
> You should now have correct colors.